# More efficient query to count group where values in range

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, group-by

I am working with data that essentially looks like this.

table:processed_data

```
sensor_id, reading, time_stamp
1,0.1,1234567890
1,0.3,1234567891
1,0.9,1234567892
1,0.32,1234567893
...
```

what I want to do is make a query that can make one loop through the data and count how many readings are in each category. Simple example,

categories (0-0.5,0.5-0.7,0.7-1) (I am actually planning on breaking them into 10 categories with 0.1 increments though).

This is essentially what I want, even though it isn't valid sql:

```
select count(reading between 0 and 0.5), count(reading between 0.5 and 0.7), count(reading between 0.7 and 1) from processed_data;
```

The only way I can think of doing it though, is to do an O*N operation, rather than a 1 time loop.

```
select count(*) as low from processed_data where reading between 0 and 0.5
union 
select count(*) as med from processed_data where reading between 0.5 and 0.7 
union
select count(*) as high from processed_data where reading between 0.7 and 1;
```

I might just resort to doing the processing in php and scan the data once, but I would prefer to have sql do it, if it can be smart enough.

Comment: In MySQL, the "isn't valid sql" would actually almost work... since COUNT increments for every non-null value (i.e. both 0 and 1), you'd want to use a SUM() aggregate in place of COUNT(). Otherwise, that query would work in MySQL. I'd expect the same query would work in sqllite.  in MySQL, the expression "`reading BETWEEN 0 AND 0.5`" is short hand for the more portable and ANSI standards compliant:  "`CASE WHEN reading BETWEEN 0 AND 0.5 THEN 1 WHEN reading NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 0.5 THEN 0 ELSE NULL END`".

Comment: Oh, interesting. I am actually looking at how I could use case for the more complex version of what I am doing. I think 'case' might be my real answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive the category from the value, and use that for grouping:

```
SELECT CAST(reading * 10 AS INTEGER),
       COUNT(*)
FROM processed_data
GROUP BY CAST(reading * 10 AS INTEGER);
```